# Updating A UIView in customView field of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationcontroller

I am keeping a score of a game in the navigation bar. 
I am trying to update the UILabel in UIBarButtonItem's customView. 
After I call setText on UILabel, it does not get updated.
I tried to change its color just to test, that also does not work.
I tried to update the UILabel  by calling setNeedsDisplay
I tried to update the customView in  UIBarButtonItem by calling setNeedsDisplay.
Non of that actually updates the view. 
I debugged and the code executes and prints the correct value on console when it gets to the line where I NSLog.

I also tried to update the whole view of navController by calling. (Current code does that below)

What is the right way to update/refresh the customView field of UIBarButtonItem

```
UIBarButtonItem* backUIButton =[view.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems objectAtIndex:1];// I have 2 items in rightBarButtonList
    UIView* settingFrame =backUIButton.customView;


    for (UIView *i in settingFrame.subviews){
        if([i isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
            UILabel *newLbl = (UILabel *)i;
            if(newLbl.tag == 1){
                /// Write your code
                NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [Utility getCoins] ];
                NSLog(@"data : %@",inStr);
                [newLbl setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
                [newLbl setText:inStr];

                [view.navigationController.view setNeedsDisplay];
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will just keep a property of the label

For example
I keep a property

```
@property (weak,nonatomic)UILabel * numlabel;
```

Here I create the custom bar item

```
UIView * customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,80,40)];
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"1";
label.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,80,40);
self.numlabel = label;
[customView addSubview:label];

UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
```

Then When I need to change

```
self.numlabel.text = @"2";
```

I have test with my XCode,it works well

Answer (score 1):

```
    @interface HomeViewController ()
    {
        UILabel *label;//Globally declare the label to make changes
    }
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
        label.text = @"First";
        UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:label];//set label as barButtonItem
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
    }
```

here, i updated the label with a buttonAction

```
    - (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
    {
        label.text = @"second";//successfully updated the label
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain more your answers?